# SQL recursion on a self-referencing table to obtain specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below:

| Id | LinkSlug | ParentPageId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | home |  | 0 |
| 2 | page2 |  | 1 |
| 3 | page3 |  | 2 |
| 4 | page11 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | page12 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | page13 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | page21 | 2 | 0 |
| 8 | page22 | 2 | 1 |
| 9 | page121 | 5 | 0 |
| 10 | page122 | 5 | 1 |
| 11 | page123 | 5 | 2 |

---

I'm sure you can already see the pattern - each `Page` can have any number of "SubPages" defined by the `ParentPageId`

I've been trying to get a query that can produce the following ordered output (without using the `LinkSlug` alphabetical ordering because they can be anything):

| Id | LinkSlug | ParentPageId | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | home |  | 0 |
| 4 | page11 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | page12 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | page121 | 5 | 0 |
| 10 | page122 | 5 | 1 |
| 11 | page123 | 5 | 2 |
| 6 | page13 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | page2 |  | 1 |
| 7 | page21 | 2 | 0 |
| 8 | page22 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | page3 |  | 2 |

---

I tried doing some self-joins and grouping but ended up with only one level of recursion so it was no good for the 3rd and potentially nth degree sub pages, and then also tried using a CTE as I understand they're good for recursive queries but somehow ended up producing the same table I started with and am now at a loss!

The more I try the worse it gets - I know I need to effectively select top levels (with null ParentPageId) ordered by [Order], then inject wherever there's sub pages ordering by [Order], and repeat until there are no children left - but no idea how to do this in SQL.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eaM7KkNx2Ss3xE4o6YAEwo/0)

And here's the fiddle script just in case:

```
CREATE TABLE [Pages](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LinkSlug] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ParentPageId] [int] NULL,
    [Order] [int] NOT NULL
);

INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (1, 'home', NULL, 0);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (2, 'page2', NULL, 1);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (3, 'page3', NULL, 2);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (4, 'page11', 1, 0);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (5, 'page12', 1, 1);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (6, 'page13', 1, 2);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (7, 'page21', 2, 0);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (8, 'page22', 2, 1);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (9, 'page121', 5, 0);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (10, 'page122', 5, 1);
INSERT into [Pages] ([Id], [LinkSlug], [ParentPageId], [Order]) VALUES (11, 'page123', 5, 2);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Ordering of subpages withing 1 Parent-page group? Or by LinkSlug? The goal is not quite clear

Comment: Or, I see.. It looks like you need to make something like Table of contents?

Comment: Yeah it's exactly a table of contents, like a site map - I originally thought it'd be very simple to have pages linked to other pages and an order for each group linked to the same page but my head is boggled :D

Comment: I should add I would know how to do it programatically in a loop but I thought there'd be a fairly easy SQL query to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a recursive CTE to build the hierarchy and maintain the sequence

**Example**

```
with cte1 as (
      Select [Id]
            ,[LinkSlug]
            ,[ParentPageId]
            ,[Order]
            ,Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by [Order]) as varchar(500))
      From   pages
      Where  [ParentPageId] is null
      Union  All
      Select cte2.[Id]
            ,cte2.[LinkSlug]
            ,cte2.[ParentPageId]
            ,cte2.[Order]
            ,Seq  = cast(concat(cte1.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by cte2.[Order])) as varchar(500))
      From   pages cte2 
      Join   cte1 on cte2.[ParentPageId] = cte1.[Id])
Select *
 From cte1
 Order By Seq
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! I figured somewhere I'd have to preserve the order but had no idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
WITH cte_org (n, id, 
    LinkSlug,
    ParentPageId) AS (
SELECT
    CAST([order] as CHAR(200)),
    id, 
    LinkSlug,
    ParentPageId
FROM       
    pages
WHERE ParentPageId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    o.n || '_' || e.[order],
    e.id,
    e.LinkSlug,
    e.ParentPageId
FROM 
    pages e
    INNER JOIN cte_org o 
        ON o.id = e.ParentPageId)

SELECT * FROM cte_org order by n;
```

Note: that in MS SQL you need to use `concat` instead of `||`; in MySQL - `+`

[image]

Comment: Nice! After using CONCAT() MS SQL was giving me a mismatch between the types so I chose the other answer as correct ,since it worked with a direct copy & paste but this is also awesome. Thank you!